# How to Update React Native Functional Component State from Storage

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs

I've got this component which is attempting to set its state using an object loaded from storage:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ReactElement } from "react-native/node_modules/@types/react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import MyClass from "./MyClass";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export default function FunCompWithState(): ReactElement {
  const [myClass, setMyClass] = useState<MyClass>(new MyClass());

  const promised = loadFromStorage();

  // I've also try calling this in a useEffect()
  promised.then(c => setMyClass(c));

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{myClass.getTitle()}</Text>
      <Text>{myClass.getValue()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

async function loadFromStorage(): Promise<MyClass | null> {
  const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@main.myClass");
  console.log(jsonValue);
  if (jsonValue != null) {
    return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
  }
  return Promise.resolve(null);
}
```

In my test, this is what I've got:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { act, render } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import FunCompWithState from "../FunCompWithState";
import MyClass from "../MyClass";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

async function setup() {
    const storedClass = new MyClass();
    storedClass.setTitle("Stored Class");
    storedClass.setValue(8);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@main.myClass", JSON.stringify(storedClass));
}

it("Render FunCompWithState", () => {
  act(() => {
      setup();
  });

  const { debug } = render(<FunCompWithState />);
  debug();
});
```

When I run my test, the `console.log(jsonValue)` that I placed in the `loadFromStorage` function outputs the correct values: `{"title":"Stored Class","value":8}`. However, the rendered component doesn't seem to have the correct values:

```html
    <View>
      <Text>

      </Text>
      <Text>
        1
      </Text>
    </View>
```

I would expect to be seeing this:

```html
    <View>
      <Text>
        Stored Class
      </Text>
      <Text>
        8
      </Text>
    </View>
```

So how can I get the correct values to be in the rendered component? Is this a problem with how I'm updating my component state or is this an issue with how I'm testing the component?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use promise here ?
It seems more complicated that it should be. Can't you just use setState in your function if your getAsyncItem is not null ?

```
  async function loadFromStorage() {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@main.myClass");
    console.log(jsonValue);
    if (jsonValue != null) {
      setMyClass(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmm. I could try something like this. In truth, I've abstracted my code a bit and I was actually hoping to have a common function that calls `AsyncStorage` and use that common function across multiple components instead of calling `AsyncStorage` in multiple places in my codebase. But instead of retrieving an object from my function, I can instead pass the setter to my function. I'll give that a shot if it's a standard practice.

Comment: It seems like this isn't working for me. It makes sense to me why it _should_ work, but it's unfortunately not.

Comment: Well if you have a state and if you want to avoid duplication you can make a custom hook and call it from your component.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I'm doing.